# JQuery: height is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to have a simple JQuery function where I enter a class name (of paragraph elements), enter a maximum height, and clamp the height of the paragraph with ellipses at the end. (using [this method](http://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/), essentially). However, I get the error:

Caught TypeError: toClamp.height is not a function

Following is my code. Any ideas?

```
function clamp(cl, height){
  var clamps = $(cl);
  for (var i = 0; i < clamps.length; i++) {
    var toClamp = clamps[i];
    while (toClamp.height() > height) {
        toClamp.text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
  }
}

$(window).load(function() {
  clamp('.clamp64', 64);
  clamp('.clamp106', 106)
})
```

Comment: What's in the clamps array?

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer if it solves your problem. :) [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to call a `jQuery` function on what your browser thinks is a `JavaScript` object. So, in order for it to work, `toClamp` needs to somehow tell your program that it is a `jQuery` object.

Try:

```
$(toClamp).height();
```

You will also encounter this same error on the next line of code calling `.text()`

change that to:

```
$(toClamp).text(...)
```

### Alternatively

Since you are using jQuery you can just use the `.each()` function to simplify things a little bit.

```
function clamp(cl, height){
  var clamps = $(cl);
  $(clamps).each(function(){
    while($(this).height() > height) {
      $(this).text(function (index, text){
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
  });
}
```

The `this` keyword here, replaces `toClamps`

Comment: @showdev you would think that, and I have encountered this on numerous occasion's whilst banging my head against the wall, where adding `$()` fixed the issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sean not a problem! Made some edits to help you out a little bit more

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a jQuery method (`.height()`) on a DOM element (`clamps[i]`). It's the issue.

There are several ways to solve your problem.

**My recommendation: cleaner loop with `.each` + access to the current element with `$(this)`**

```
function clamp(cl, height){
  var clamps = $(cl);
  clamps.each(function () { // Iterate on jQuery objects
    var toClamp = $(this);  // Keep a reference of the current jQuery object
    while (toClamp.height() > height) {
        toClamp.text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
  });
}
```

**Similar to your approach, with `.eq(index)` instead of `[index]`**

```
function clamp(cl, height){
  var clamps = $(cl);
  for (var i = 0; i < clamps.length; i++) {
    var toClamp = clamps.eq(i); // get the n jQuery object
    while (toClamp.height() > height) {
        toClamp.text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**Another one, but redundant in my opinion (recommended by the other answers)**

```
function clamp(cl, height){
  var clamps = $(cl);
  for (var i = 0; i < clamps.length; i++) {
    var toClamp = clamps[i];
    while ($(toClamp).height() > height) { // convert (again) a DOM element into a jQuery object
        toClamp.text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `toClamp.height` instead od `toClamp.height()`. `height` is actually not a function, but its a property or an attribute to the element. Therefore there is no need to use the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
var toClamp = $(clamps[i]);
```

?

You probably operate jQuery functions on non-jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

I am at work so I can't go too into this right now but I believe yourerror is coming from your logic in the while loop.

here:

```
while(toClamp.height() > height) ...
```

You're saying that toClamp has it's on height function but you haven't actually made the function.

If you don't want to have a height function; -- you could, but that's up to you; 
would it not be possible to do something like

this:

```
function clamp(cl, h1){
var clamps = $(cl);
var height = $(h1);
for (var i = 0; i < clamps.length; i++) {
var toClamp = clamps[i];
while (toClamp.h1 > height) {
    toClamp.text(function (index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
     });
    }
  }
}

$(window).load(function() {
clamp('.clamp64', 64);
clamp('.clamp106', 106)`enter code here`
})
```

This is not tested as of yet but I will look into it further when I get home.